# Disabling the scrollview right side at some conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I am implementing horizontal scrollview with 10 custom views each view is having different UI. when user scroll left I am scrolling to  next view and on right scrolling to previous view it is working fine till now.At some conditions I have to restrict the left scrolling and enable only right scrolling.
In below method i am getting scenarios when to disable the right scrolling

```
-(void)scrollEnabled:(BOOL)scrollEnable
{
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = scrollEnable;
    // scrollEnable comes NO at some conditions here i have to disable the right scrolling.
    if(!scrollEnable)
    {
        // Now i am registering the pan gesture and detecting the right swiping
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(detectRightScroll:)];
        [self.panView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

    }
}

- (void) detectRightScroll:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:gesture.view];
    if(translation > 0) // here detecting the right scrolling and changing the scrollview content offset
    {
        [scrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x-translation, 0)];
        view is scrolling but not scrolling like scrooview
    }
}
```

Can we achieve my requirement without registering the gesture.
i strucked with this issue from last 4 days but not able to solve.
Any help can be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset the `contentOffset` of `UIScrollView` if it's wrong direction (or disable that direction)

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > stopPosition) { // or (scrollView.contentOffset.x < stopPosition)
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(stopPosition, 0)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi anthu thanks for your reply. Just for clarification i am implementing horizontal scrolling but your updating the y position which is for vertical scrolling. Why

Comment: Sorry, I don't notice that. But I hope you can understand my answer. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
 scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView )scrollView and - (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView )scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

        int xFinal = self.yourScroll.contentOffset.x ;
        int viewIndex = xFinal / (yourImageSize);
        xFinal = viewIndex *  yourImageSize ;
        [self.yourScroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(xFinal, 0) animated:YES];
}




- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
        int xFinal = self.yourScroll.contentOffset.x  ;
        int viewIndex = xFinal / yourImageSize ;
         xFinal = viewIndex *  yourImageSize;
        [self.yourScroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(xFinal, 0) animated:YES];
}
```

And you will be able to scroll only in the limit of your images array count.

Comment: Hi ErmineSoft i will implement your suggestions and let you know thanks